# Bootstrap column ordering

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having a bit of a mental block - I'm sure there's a simple solution to this, but I'm just not getting it...

I'm trying to achieve the following layout. The top image is a mobile layout and the lower is a desktop layout.

**Note:** These are meant to represent a single area at Mobile and Desktop view ports not two sections on a single page.

[image]

I've attempted to build what I would need in [This Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnvbjk2g/) but it's not right, and I can't figure out how to do this without duplicating div #3.

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="pad col-sm-8">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="pad a col-xs-12"></div>
      <div class="pad c col-xs-12"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pad b col-sm-4"></div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="pad col-xs-8">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="pad a col-xs-12"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pad b col-xs-4"></div>
  <div class="pad c col-xs-12"></div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to achieve the layout I'm after without having to duplicate div #3? I could very easily get what I wanted by using duplicate divs but that's obviously not desirable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a pull-right on div b?

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="pad b col-xs-4 col-md-4 pull-right"></div>
  <div class="pad a col-xs-8 col-md-8"></div>
  <div class="pad c col-xs-12 col-md-8"></div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Updated Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/kfyLLvt5/2/

Comment: Genius - Exactly what I need. Knew there'd be something that could be done with push or pulls, just didn't know what! Thanks =]

Answer (score 0):

Try this: It's like in your image:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="pad col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="pad a col-xs-8"></div>
      <div class="pad c col-xs-4"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pad b col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="pad col-xs-8">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="pad a col-xs-12"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pad b col-xs-4"></div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not quite right - col a and b need to essentially stay in place, the height is not really relevant. Col c needs to be under col a on mobile, and under both a and b at desktop size plus full width.